# Good reference for topological Hochschild homology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, noncommutative-geometry

I want to start reading topological Hochschild homology(THH) as well as topological cyclic homology (TC).

I have read the Hochschild homology and cyclic homology from the book Cyclic homology by J. Loday. This is very fantastic written book. Can someone suggest me some good reference like this for THH/TC?

Answer (score 8):

As a first introduction I like [these notes](https://www.uni-muenster.de/IVV5WS/WebHop/user/nikolaus/Papers/Lectures.pdf) by Achim Krause and Thomas Nikolaus. They do require some familiarity with spectra and stable homotopy theory though.

Answer (score 8):

Ib Madsen's [survey](http://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cdm/1995/1995/0001/CDM-1995-1995-0001-a003.pdf)

> MR1474979 (98g:19004) Madsen, Ib Algebraic K-theory and traces.
> Current developments in mathematics, 1995 (Cambridge, MA), 191–321,
> Int. Press, Cambridge, MA, 1994.

was written to be such an introduction, but is 25 years old. Its technical foundations are given in terms of FSPs (functors with smash product).  A more recent source is the [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447143925)

> MR3013261  Dundas, Bjørn Ian; Goodwillie, Thomas G; McCarthy, Randy
> The local structure of algebraic K-theory. Algebra and Applications,
> 18. Springer-Verlag London, Ltd., London, 2013. xvi+435 pp. ISBN: 978-1-4471-4392-5; 978-1-4471-4393-2

which works with $\Gamma$-rings (= monoids in $\Gamma$-spaces). Both of these predate the connection to crystalline and syntomic cohomology.